# Unable to retrieve permissions if file was shared to a group and group is deleted

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm having an issue with the Google Drive api. If you share a document out to a group, then the group is deleted, the permissions of the file are no longer able to be pulled.

Steps to reproduce.
1. Create document in drive through UI
2. Shared document out to a google internal group
3. Delete group through cPanel.
4. Try to pull permission of file using drive api.

Language : Java 
Drive API : v2
Call :

```
public static void retrievePermissions(Drive serv, ArrayList<Permission> perms, String userEmail, String fileId, String title) throws Exception {  

PermissionList permissions = null;  
int retry = 5;  

while (retry > 0) { 
   try {  
       permissions = serv.permissions().list(fileId).execute();  
       perms.addAll(permissions.getItems());  
       retry = 0;  
   }catch(com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException je){  
       je.printStackTrace();  
       System.err.println("JSON EXCEPTION DOC TITLE :: " + title + " :: user " + userEmail);  
       retry = 0;  
} catch (Exception e) {  
       retry = retryError(e, retry, printStackTrace);  
       if (retry == 0)  
       throw e;  
}  
}  
}
```

Error Msg :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 OK
{
"code" : 500,
"message" : null
}
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:143)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:114)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:417)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
at com.promevo.gsd.utils.gData_Drive_Util.retrievePermissions(gData_Drive_Util.java:119)
at com.promevo.gsd.docs.Initial_Run_Docs.doAcls(Initial_Run_Docs.java:254)
at com.promevo.gsd.docs.Initial_Run_Docs.storeDocs(Initial_Run_Docs.java:224)
at com.promevo.gsd.docs.Initial_Run_Docs.pullPageOfDocs(Initial_Run_Docs.java:188)
at com.promevo.gsd.docs.Initial_Run_Docs.doWork(Initial_Run_Docs.java:108)
at com.promevo.gsd.docs.Initial_Run_Docs.run(Initial_Run_Docs.java:99)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DeferredTaskServlet.performRequest(DeferredTaskServlet.java:136)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DeferredTaskServlet.service(DeferredTaskServlet.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This does look like a bug. I will try to reproduce and get back to you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get the list of permission as normal including the group's permission. Should I wait a while after deleting the group?

Comment: I tried with internal and external groups too.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is affecting just old docs, I thought I was able to reproduce this.  I was testing on a large amount of docs and when the group goes to "Unknown Group" in the UI is when this occurs.  I have a bunch of document Id's I can give you as well.  I can make you an an account on my dev domain if you would like so you can pull these docs.  I can PM you the info if you can take a look.

Comment: Just looked at my last test.  It must take some time to propagate to the document when the group is deleted.  The test I created yesterday is now producing the exception.  Can you please try your test again.

Comment: I just tried again now with the same script and I am still getting no error.

Comment: So was the group added to the document, then deleted out of cPanel and leave the group acl in the document, and now showing in the UI of the document as "Unknown Group"? Again, I have multiple instances of these if there is someway to give you the document id's so you can try pulling.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this same behavior using the python libraries, as son as as 'Unknown Group' appears in the permissions list i get 500 error back.